# How to override react-data-grid styles with Material-UI in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles, material-ui

Let's say i have a file with themes:

themes.js:

```
import {createMuiTheme} from "@material-ui/core/styles";

export const myTheme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        text: {
            color: "#545F66",
        },
    },
});
```

And file with App.js, where render looks something like this:

```
return (
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <MyComponent />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
```

Now i know that i can access the theme via withStyles:

```
const StyledMyComponent = withStyles(theme => ({
    something: {
        color: theme.palette.text.color
    }    
}))(props => <MyComponent {...props} />);
```

But what i want to achieve is something different.
MyComponent is a very big component and has for example class called "react-table-1"
And the thing i want is to set the class color "react-table-1" to theme.palette.text
so something like this:

```
const StyledMyComponent = withStyles(theme => ({
    "react-table-1": {
        color: theme.palette.text
    }    
}))(props => <MyComponent {...props} />);
```

But obviously it doesn't work.
Does anyone know if this is possible ? And how can i achieve that.

I can set "react-table-1" color in css file but i want to change it inside
react via button, and that's why i need something like this.

Live demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jt9xs1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to try [nesting-selectors](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#nesting-selectors) for className

I found that you can't simply add `className` to `ReactDataGrid`, it's probably related to this lib, you can make a workaround for it.

Some notice points:

- If you check the DOM structure, you would find out that the `ReactDataGrid` Root class is `react-grid-Container`, not `react-grid-Main`
- Material-UI `withStyles` is used as a HOC for component, for specific usage plz refer to the link at the bottom.
- The problem in the post is rarely related to Theme, you can use your Theme as normal.
- If you want to bind your button with styles, make an outer layer of styles hooks and pass the state down to `makeStyles` would be fine.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDataGrid from "react-data-grid";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const columns = [
  { key: "id", name: "ID" },
  { key: "title", name: "Title" },
  { key: "complete", name: "Complete" }
];

const rows = [
  { id: 0, title: "Task 1", complete: 20 },
  { id: 1, title: "Task 2", complete: 40 },
  { id: 2, title: "Task 3", complete: 60 }
];

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    "& div.react-grid-Container": {
      color: "red",
      // color: theme.palette.text.color
    }
  }
}));

const App = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [row, setRow] = useState([]);
  const onBrutForce = e => {};
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <ReactDataGrid
        columns={columns}
        rowGetter={i => rows[i]}
        rowsCount={3}
        enableCellSelect={true}
      />
      <br />
      This is what i want to achieve but with "ChangeTheme" button. <br />
      Because i want to set the style to other components too. <br />
      <button onClick={onBrutForce} style={{ margin: "10px" }}>
        (click me)
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: Edit strange-worker-4pk8w]

---

Related styling QA:

- [Functional and classical styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736015/how-to-change-material-ui-textfield-label-styles-in-react/60736142#60736142)
- [Convert functional to classical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60743946/material-ui-styles-convert-functional-component-to-class-component/60743980#60743980)